# Transfer string data to bytes

Tags: c++builder

I am a freshman in C++. Here is my code to load a text file into a `TMemo` component.

```
void _fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
   file_rd=fopen(rd_file,'r');
   if(file_rd==NULL){
     Memo1->Lines->Add("NULL TEXT");
   }
   fread(data,100,1,file_rd);
   Memo1->Lines->Add(d);
   fclose(file_rd);
}
```

However, I'm confused about the conversion of data. If I want to show Bytes in the Memo, I need to run some conversion function with the data. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: `TMemo` has a `LoadFromFile()` method: `Memo1->Lines->LoadFromFile(rd_file);`. Your `data` buffer is not null terminated, but passing a buffer to `Add()` requires a null terminator. Otherwise you have to use the `String` constructor that accepts a buffer size as input: `size = fread(data,100,1,file_rd); Memo1->Lines->Add(String(data, size));` But you did not say which version of C++Builder you are using. In CB2007 and earlier, `TMemo` works with ANSI strings. In CB2009 and later, it works with Unicode strings. You are not taking character encoding into account at all.

Comment: And `TMemo` displays only text, so if you need to show raw non-printable bytes, you have to convert them to a human-readable format, such as hex. The RTL has [`BinToHex()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.BinToHex) functions for that purpose